# Grafana send notification for each error log

Tags: logging, prometheus, grafana

In my Grafana dashboard, I count the number of "error logs" and send alert if there is at least 1 error.

This is the query I use

```
count_over_time(({logtype="app_log"} |= "ERROR")[1h])
```

This line counts the lines that includes "ERROR" in the last hour and returns the count.
Then, I would like to send an alert to the dev channel, if there is such log (either 1 log, or 1000 log).

In Alert tab, I have added a rule:

Rule

- Name: ${RuleName}
- Evaluate every: 60m
- For: 0

Conditions

```
WHEN count () OF query (A, 60m, now) IS ABOVE 0
```

If no data or all values are null

```
SET STATE TO <OK>
```

If execution error or timeout

```
SET STATE TO <ALERTING>
```

I am missing some parts in here and I need help:

- I want to receive a notification at each hour, if there is an error log. Currently, this configuration wait for 1 hour, then executes the query, finds out that it has an error log, and sends notification. That is correct. Then, in the next hour, it once again searches for the logs in the last hour, finds out at least another error log, but does not send a notification, because it is already in alerting state. I want to send another notification to the dev channel because in the last execution, there is another error and I want to know it.
- The second missing part happens like in the following: In the 1st hour, there is at least 1 error and I receive a notification. Then, in the second hour there is no error and I receive again notification, but this time it is "OK". I tried different combinations but couldn't find a workaround to this. I don't want to receive a notification if there is error in the 1st hour but not in the 2nd hour.
- In the notification part, I want to know when this error happened, what was the error message, etc. I know it is doable via templating or via ${}, but in the message part, I do not have access to the log line. How can I add the erroneous log to the notification?

Comment: It's been asked so many times - there is got to be a solution. Have you found anything yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is the solution that comes to my mind, but I haven't implemented or tested it yet. Servers are not busy during the night, so logscan can be configured (I don't know how) to scan nightly. Then, after the scan, a cronjob could delete this monitoring via API and create a newer one. So that, each 24 hour we can run the query once, and then delete the query. Not ideal, but could work...

Comment: Why do you evaluate every 60m? If you evaluate every 1m the alarm would be fired whenever the count of errors in the last hour was over the limit.

Comment: And you can add a repeat interval to the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I just know about third question.
I do sum query:

```
    sum by (message, ts, smthelse) 
(count_over_time(
```

And then I'm able to use them in notification text. It works weird in some situations, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get *exactly* what you want. But at least you can try the following:

- Set the "Repeat interval" of the notification to 1h.
- Set "Evaluate every" to some small value such as 1m.

[image: Example]

The example shows 3 errors that generate 3 notifications. (Note that the number of errors and the number of notifications will not always match, it is just an example.)

The first notification is due to error 1, the second due to error 2. The first notification will not be repeated, because we are not in alert state at this point in time. The second notification will be repeated because due to error 3 we are still in alert state.